# How To Delete A Specific Table Row In PowerPoint Using Python-PPTX

Tags: python-pptx

How can we delete specific rows in a PowerPoint Presentation table using Python-PPTX? It is possible to loop through each row/column and cell but there doesn't appear to be a way to delete a specific row?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'built in' way to do this but by editing the underlying XML we can get the result we want.

```
import pptx
from pptx import *

def remove_row(table, row):
    tbl = table._tbl
    tr = row._tr
    tbl.remove(tr)

# Establish read path
in_file_path = "input.pptx"

# Open slide-show presentation
pres = Presentation(in_file_path)

# Get Table
for slide in pres.slides:
    for shp in slide.shapes:
        if shp.has_table:
            table = shp.table
                
            row = table.rows[7]
            remove_row(table, row)

pres.save("output.pptx")
```