# Delete column in python-pptx table

Tags: python, python-pptx

Hi I have seen [How To Delete A Specific Table Row In PowerPoint Using Python-PPTX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73364745/how-to-delete-a-specific-table-row-in-powerpoint-using-python-pptx) on deleting rows in python-pptx table which is more than helpful, however I realised that deleting columns is not as straightforward as this, was wondering if there's a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but again through editing the XML

```
import pptx
from pptx import *

def remove(table,column):
    col_idx = table._tbl.tblGrid.index(column._gridCol)

    for tr in table._tbl.tr_lst:
        tr.remove(tr.tc_lst[col_idx])
    table._tbl.tblGrid.remove(column._gridCol)



# Establish read path
in_file_path = "input.pptx"

# Open slide-show presentation
pres = Presentation(in_file_path)

# Get Table
for slide in pres.slides:
    for shp in slide.shapes:
        if shp.has_table:
            table = shp.table
            remove(table, table.columns[2])
pres.save("output.pptx")
```